# Scapy proxy HTTP packet

Tags: python, networking, tcp, scapy, netfilter

I want to send an HTTP packet to port 31112, but I want to change the IP identification header to 0xabcd.

What I am doing is using iptables for, whatever packet with destination port 31112, redirect it to a queue:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 31112-j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
```

I have also enabled forwarding:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

My program is this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue
from scapy.all import *
def print_and_accept(pkt):
    
    
    data = pkt.get_payload()
    
    ip_h = IP(data)
    
    
    print ('source: '  + ip_h[IP].src)
    print ('destination: ' + ip_h[IP].dst)
    print ('IP TTL: ' + str(ip_h[IP].ttl))
    print (str (ip_h[TCP].payload))
    
    ip_h[IP].ttl = 40
    
    ip_h[IP].id = 0xabcd
    #print  (ip_h[IP].id)
    del ip_h[IP].chksum

    send(ip_h,verbose=0)
    
    

nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(1, print_and_accept)
try:
    nfqueue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ('\nProgram Ended')
```

And, when I send a curl to my destination:

```
curl http://serverexample.com:31112/
```

I get this in my program's output:

```
source: 192.168.206.128
destination: 35.182.181.240
IP TTL: 64
```

It is weird that I don't capture this:

print (str (ip_h[TCP].payload))

which I think it must be something like "GET / HTTP/1.1"  and whatever headers might follow.

I want to know if someone can spot the issue.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You change the source of the TCP SYN, which means that the SYN+ACK from the server gets send to the IP address you gave at source - and thus does not arrive at your system. This means the TCP handshake will not be completed. But transfer of application data (i.e. the HTTP messages) will only be done after a completed TCP handshake.

Comment: Any idea? I don't know if I can specify with iptables to redirect not TCP packets but the HTTP one

Comment: @aDoN: *"Any idea?"* - You are trying to spoof the source IP for TCP, i.e. using a source IP where you cannot receive data. This is mostly impossible. There are some attacks but they rely on large bandwidth and zillions of packets in the hope to guess the peers sequence number correctly - since the response of the peer can not be observed.